# Is JobID same for daily running journeys in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, triggered-send, data-views, jobid

When we send one-off emails from marketing cloud, JobID can be used to identify the email deployment as it is unique.

When it comes to journeys (in use-case where audience is entering the journey daily):

1. Does JobID stays the same throughout the life of the journey?
2. Does JobID changes after sometime? if yes, on what basis?
3. How JobID is generated for a journey send?
4. How JobID can be used to show the total emails send for a journey series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JobIDs for any triggered emails (including Journey Builder sends) persist until a publish event.

To answer you questions specifically:

1. Does JobID stays the same throughout the life of the journey?

> Not necessarily

2. Does JobID changes after sometime? if yes, on what basis?

> New JobIDs are assigned for sends after a publish event occurs on the send definition

4. How JobID is generated for a journey send?

> It's no different than any other send

5. How JobID can be used to show the total emails send for a journey series?

> If you retrieve the aggregated Send SOAP object you can see the progression.  [Here's the script I use](https://sprignaturemoves.com/retrieving-and-storing-aggregated-send-data/) for doing that.  You can use this data to join back to the `_Journey` and `_JourneyActivity` data views to associate the sends to a specific journey.

Here's a query that illustrates the connection between the journey data and the send job:

**Journey Jobs**

```sql
select
  j.jobid
, j.emailName
, jn.journeyName
, jn.versionNumber
from _Job j
inner join _JourneyActivity ja on ja.JourneyActivityObjectID = j.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
inner join _Journey jn on jn.VersionID = ja.VersionID
where 1=1 
and convert(varchar(36),ja.JourneyActivityObjectID) != '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
and isnull(ja.ActivityName,'') != ''
```

Comment: Hi Adam - thank you for the query, it is definitely helpful. I am 100% following on using TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID (not JobID) to joining the tables. One item where I would appreciate if you could please elaborate on is, what you mean by "_JobIDs for any triggered emails (including Journey Builder sends) persist until a publish event."_ For example - if I activate journey version 1. the journey gets new audience daily and it runs for 1 year, does that mean jobid will stay same? will only change when I will publish version2?

Comment: same question for TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID, it looks like it changes with time as well but on what basis it stays same and what makes it change? In my journey, I am seeing withing same version there are multiple TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID, how is that possible?

Comment: Just had a thought, by publish event, did you meant, if we pause a journey and resume that means a new jobid and TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID will be created after each resume? and if we never touch a journey, jobid and TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID will always stay the same. Publish event can be anything, pause / resume OR a new version. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @kuml2 Publish event is when you manually publish via Email Studio (TriggeredSendDefinitions) or when you make an edit in Journey Builder to an email and it republishes it for you automatically so that the changes you made are reflected in the email being sent.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Adam said.

1. no
2. The jobID is changed when you update to a new version.

Plus, it also changes when you save the email content *within* a running version, which works without version update. All you need to do is open the email content in the Journey Builder Email Activity, and hit "done", you do not even need to make actual changes. Once you see the screen that says something like "do not close this window", you get a new job Id. The notification is there because in the background, SFMC stops the triggered send, publishes changes, restarts. Next send from this journey will have a new jobid.

3. not sure what you want to understand here, skipping
4. jobId alone cannot do that, it is mutable. What I would do is custom track an ID that come up yourself, you enter to the relevant emails, and store it in a sendlog next to jobId / listid / batchid / subscriberkey. That way, you also have an immutable ID across email versions / content changes that relates to jobs and thus sends, opens , clicks etc.